# TypeError: React.createContext is not a function (Nextjs 13 & Formik with Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, formik

I am now trying to create a form on NextJs 13 (Typescript) with Formik. The form that I created doesn't work then I tried adding the example code snippets from `Formik` as you could see below. Both the form I created and Formik's examples are only returning `TypeError: React.createContext is not a function` in console. I could see this `(sc_server)/./node_modules/formik/dist/formik.cjs.development.js` in another line of console error.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Formik,
  FormikHelpers,
  FormikProps,
  Form,
  Field,
  FieldProps,
} from 'formik';

interface MyFormValues {
  firstName: string;
}

export const MyApp: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const initialValues: MyFormValues = { firstName: '' };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Example</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          console.log({ values, actions });
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I imported above component in /app/page.tsx as the following.

```
import { MyApp } from '../components/form/MyApp';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyApp />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 35):

I got the same error but with Material UI's DataTable.

DataTable makes use of React Context API, and such API is only available to client side components: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-_documentjs-and-_appjs

Adding 'use client'; on top of the page fixed the error to me. It may be the case with Formik.

Comment: Hello @WindWalker, I have tried adding 'use client' at the top of the page but it just throws the same error. For now, I just moved the related files to the /pages directory and it's working fine. Once there is a solution, I may move them back to /the app directory.

Answer (score 25):

With the new **App Directory**, React Components are categorized into two: Server Components and Client Components, and by default they are all Server Component as mentioned here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs.

Components that need hooks (context, use..., or as such as your case with Formik) needs to be classified as Client Components and they need to have the directive "use client" at the top of the source file, before any import (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs).

So your code should be like this:

```
'use client';

import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Formik,
  FormikHelpers,
  FormikProps,
  Form,
  Field,
  FieldProps,
} from 'formik';
// ...more code
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `use client` in the first line in `MyApp` and `Home` components. because next13 uses client and sever component.

Also check this link https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error but with Chakra UI.

ChakraUI  makes use of React Context API, and such API is only available to client side components: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-_documentjs-and-_appjs

Adding 'use client'; on top of the page fixed the error to me. It may be the case with Formik.

Answer (score 2):

I was import an icon from material icon and i got this error. I simply use `'use client'` in the top of my header component.

Here is the code:

```
'use client';

import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import SearchRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchRounded';

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
        {/* topNav */}
        <div className='flex items-center bg-amazon_blue p-4 flex-grow pb-1'>
            <div className="mt-2 flex items-center flex-grow sm:flex-grow-0">
                <Image 
                src="https://links.papareact.com/f90"
                width={100}
                height={50}
                priority
                />
            </div>
            {/* Search */}
           <div>
            <input type="text"/>
            <SearchRoundedIcon/>
           </div>
        </div>
        {/* bottomNav */}
        <div></div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1):

add 'use client' tot he top of your component to make it client based.
no its not .. but know anytime u use something that require client inputs or anything that require to be run directly on client like some libraries which are for motions , then u will always need to wrap your component as client side

Comment: Is this different from (more helpful than) any of the other existing answers which already mention `use client`?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please consider adding more details as the answer does not provide any new information as compared to other answers provided.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> Adding 'use client'; on top of the page fixed the error to me.

I had this problem trying to integrate headlessui/react in my app

```
'use client';

import Image from 'next/image'
import TestimonialImage from '@/public/images/testimonial.jpg'
import { Disclosure } from '@headlessui/react'
import { BsFillPlusCircleFill } from 'react-icons/bs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this question just type 'use client' on the top of your component.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone had the simialar error but for radix:

```js
⨯ node_modules/@radix-ui/react-context/dist/index.mjs (34:63) @ defaultContext ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
```

Error Message:

```
⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 ✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 389ms (1057 modules)
 ○ Compiling /api/users ...
 ✓ Compiled /api/users in 1356ms (1091 modules)
 ⨯ node_modules/@radix-ui/react-checkbox/dist/index.mjs (25:123) @ $e698a72e93240346$var$CHECKBOX_NAME
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , _radix_ui_react_context__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.createContextScope) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-checkbox/dist/index.mjs:32:173)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-checkbox/dist/index.mjs (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/vendor-chunks/@radix-ui.js:80:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/lib/utils/constants/index.tsx:22:82)
    at (rsc)/./src/lib/utils/constants/index.tsx (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:502:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/users/route.ts:11:78)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/api/users/route.ts (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:252:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute.ts&appDir=%2Fhome%2Frockyessel%2FDesktop%2Fclogarr%2Fblogengine%2Fsrc%2Fapp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=%2Fhome%2Frockyessel%2FDesktop%2Fclogarr%2Fblogengine&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!:17:128)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Froute.ts&appDir=%2Fhome%2Frockyessel%2FDesktop%2Fclogarr%2Fblogengine%2Fsrc%2Fapp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=%2Fhome%2Frockyessel%2FDesktop%2Fclogarr%2Fblogengine&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D! (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:242:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:522:39)
    at /home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:523:1368
    at __webpack_require__.X (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:163:21)
    at /home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:523:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/.next/server/app/api/users/route.js:526:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at mod.require (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at requirePage (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:109:84)
    at /home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:59:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:59:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/home/rockyessel/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:671:36) {
  page: '/api/users'
}
null
```

1. delete `node_modules` & `.next`
2. run `npm outdated`

```
rockyessel@UBUNTU-ROCKY:~/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine$ npm outdated
Package                Current   Wanted   Latest  Location                            Depended by
@tanstack/react-table   8.10.7   8.11.0   8.11.0  node_modules/@tanstack/react-table  blogengine
@types/node             20.9.1  20.10.5  20.10.5  node_modules/@types/node            blogengine
@types/react           18.2.37  18.2.45  18.2.45  node_modules/@types/react           blogengine
@types/react-dom       18.2.15  18.2.18  18.2.18  node_modules/@types/react-dom       blogengine
date-fns                2.30.0   2.30.0    3.0.0  node_modules/date-fns               blogengine
eslint                  8.53.0   8.56.0   8.56.0  node_modules/eslint                 blogengine
eslint-config-next      14.0.1   14.0.1   14.0.4  node_modules/eslint-config-next     blogengine
lucide-react           0.292.0  0.292.0  0.298.0  node_modules/lucide-react           blogengine
mongoose                 8.0.1    8.0.3    8.0.3  node_modules/mongoose               blogengine
next-sanity              7.0.0    7.0.4    7.0.4  node_modules/next-sanity            blogengine
postcss                 8.4.31   8.4.32   8.4.32  node_modules/postcss                blogengine
recharts                 2.9.3   2.10.3   2.10.3  node_modules/recharts               blogengine
sonner                   1.2.2    1.2.4    1.2.4  node_modules/sonner                 blogengine
tailwind-merge           2.0.0    2.1.0    2.1.0  node_modules/tailwind-merge         blogengine
tailwindcss              3.3.5    3.3.7    3.3.7  node_modules/tailwindcss            blogengine
typescript               5.2.2    5.3.3    5.3.3  node_modules/typescript             blogengine
rockyessel@UBUNTU-ROCKY:~/Desktop/clogarr/blogengine$ npm install @tanstack/react-table@latest
```

3. update every package to the latest version
4. finally run `npm run dev`

```
 ○ Compiling /api/auth/[...nextauth] ...
 ✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 1861ms (1057 modules)
 ○ Compiling /api/users ...
 ✓ Compiled /api/users in 784ms (1079 modules)
MongoDB Connection Successful
 ✓ Compiled /api/users/validate in 308ms (1081 modules)
MongoDB Connection Successful
 ✓ Compiled /api/users/field in 286ms (1083 modules)
MongoDB Connection Successful
```

Now everything works. So if any ever get into such a problem try the steps to resolve.